# funcion onkeypress javascript

Tags: javascript

me encuentro en un problema necesito comparar el valor de dos inputs  que si uno es mayor que el otro me devuelva un mensaje de alerta, necesito comparar cuando presiono el valor en uno de los inputs pero no me funciona

Adjunto lo que intente

```js
function myFunction() {
    var cants = document.getElementById('cants').value;
    var cant = document.getElementById('cant').value;
    if (cants > cant){
      alert("Es mayor");
    }
}
```

```html
<p> campos .</p>
    
    <input type="text" id="cants" onkeydown="myFunction()">
    <input type="text" id ="cant" onkeypress="myFunction()" value="20" readonly >
```

Comment: Gracias Alberto

Comment: Como puedo hacer el script

Comment: Perdon por mi ignorancia pero solo cambiaste de lugar la funcion

Comment: No, hice un snippet (un código asilado y compilado), eso nos sirve para hacer pruebas más eficientes sin tener que escribir en nuestras máquinas el código.

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza `onkeyup` es más eficiente. Optimicé la lógica de decisión. Que te sirva

```js
function myFunction() {
    var cants = parseInt( document.getElementById('cants').value );
    var cant = parseInt( document.getElementById('cant').value );
    
    if( cant && cants ){
      console.log( `cants es ${cants} y cant es ${cant}` );
      if (cants > cant){
        alert("Es mayor");
      }
    }
    
}
```

```html
<p> campos .</p>
    
    <input type="text" id="cants" onkeyup="myFunction()">
    <input type="text" id ="cant" onkeyup="myFunction()" value="20" readonly >
```

Answer (score 1):

Te anexo un ejemplo, añadí un botón "Comparar", al momento de presionarlo compara el primer valor con el segundo, en caso de que sea mayor el primero entonces muestra el `alert`:

```js
function myFunction() { 
var cants = document.getElementById('cants').value; 
var cant = document.getElementById('cant').value; 
if (cants > cant){ alert("Es mayor"); 
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cants">
<input type="text" id="cant">


<button onclick="myFunction()">Comparar</button>
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: El script esta antes de los campos ???

Comment: el script lo puedes agregar dentro del tag <script>//Aquí el script</script> de tu html.

Comment: o también puedes crear un archivo de Javascript y le haces referencia desde tu html.

Answer (score 0):

Hola te recomiendo utilizar las sintaxis para javascript con jquery:

```
$("#cants").on("keypress",function(){

       var cants = $("#cants").val()

   }
);
```

Comment: A que te refieres con nuevas?

Comment: Les doy las gracias a todos probare con onkeyup